# Hiding PickerView and Box To Show What Was Selected

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am working on implementing something in my iOS app that I see in mobile websites all the time.  I would like to have a TextBox or TextField of some kind that shows what value is currently selected.  When clicked, it will present a UIPickerView with a list of possible choices.  Upon selection, the UIPickerView will disappear, and the TextBox or TextField would get updated with the selection the user made.  Can someone point me in a good direction for doing this?

Comment: That's pretty basic stuff. Have you looked at Apple's API docs and sample code?

Comment: I've looked through a lot of stuff.  If it is pretty basic stuff, perhaps you wouldn't mind pointing me to a specific part of the api docs and sample code you are speaking of?  I know perfectly well how to use a UIPickerView but not how to display its selection when it is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save indexPath value in a string and show it on textfield like: [textField setText:NSString];